# connection refused on email sending

Tags: laravel, amazon-ses

I am working on a Laravel project and added SES for sending emails. It works fine on localhost, but after moving to the live server, it doesn't send any emails and gives this error on this command.

When I try to send an email from the website, it gives the error: 'Connection could not be established with host "email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:587": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect.'

I have logged into WHM and checked SMTP restrictions; they are already disabled. I've also tried the tweaks, but it's still not working. I have also check the firewall cpanel is already added there

When i run this command in terminal it gives the error below

```
openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -starttls smtp -connect email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:465
```

Error below

```
140149841614656:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
140149841614656:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
140149841614656:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
140149841614656:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
140149841614656:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
140149841614656:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=111
```

Comment: Check with your host, they may be blocking ports to other mail services.